# Find and replace multiple files using... sublime?

Tags: regex, search, replace, sublimetext3

I have a lot of files which I'd like to find and replace

`<tags:message code="SOME_KEY" />` or `<tags:message code='SOME_KEY' />`

into 
`_(SOME_KEY)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex in your find:

```
<tags:message code="(.+)" />
```

and replace with

```
_($1)
```

Be sure to have regex enabled when you do search and replace.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching for entries on 'find results' you can press `ctrl + shift + f` again (I think for mac uses is `cmd + shift + f`) Then click Replace.

Sublime will ask something like that: "Replaces 99 occurrence across 17 files?"

The only problem is that it will not save the files for you, will just open the files with the new value.

I tested it here on Sublime Text 3 and it worked

I hope it helped a bit :)

[image: find]

[image: Find again]

[image: replace]